# gradient equality with integral?

Tags: real-analysis

i have this question, that i found in a book, how did the autor do this developement :

$\int_\Omega|\nabla(u+t\phi)|^6dx=\int_\Omega|\nabla(u)|^6dx+6t\int_\Omega|\nabla(u)|^4\nabla u.\nabla\phi dx+o(t)$ 
thank you very much

$u,\phi$ are smooth functions , $\Omega$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Multiply out: $(a+tb)^6=a^6+6ta^5b+o(t^2)+...$.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb - That is almost right. Remember that since these are vectors, $$\begin{align}|\nabla(u+t\phi)|^6 &= (\nabla(u+t\phi)\cdot\nabla(u+t\phi))^3\\&=(|\nabla u|^2 + 2t\nabla u\cdot\nabla \phi + t^2|\nabla \phi|^2)^3\\&=|\nabla u|^6 + 6t|\nabla u|^4\nabla u\cdot\nabla \phi + o(t^2)\end{align}$$